# Google Maps APIv3 about handling multiple markers

Tags: ajax, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have some code I put together and I see that there must be some problem with zLat and zLng. I am wondering why it is when I replace zLat and zLng with tLat and tLng inside my for loop then I get one marker which makes sense. With zLat and zLng in there I get no markers. Why would this be happening?

P.S. My alert for zLat and zLng is producing what looks like proper output but it must not be?

```
    // // // // // // // // Ajax returns from PHP
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var tLat = getCookie("tLat");
        var tLng = getCookie("tLng");

        var options = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7257, -74.0047),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Creating the map  
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

        // Adding a marker to the map
        /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(tLat, tLng),
          map: map,
          title: 'Click me',
          icon: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/blank.png'
        });*/

        var marker;

        alert(obj.length);

        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {

            var zLat = String(obj[i].lat);
            var zLng = String(obj[i].lng);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(zLat, zLng),
              map: map,
              title: 'Click me'
            });

            alert(zLat+','+zLng+','+i); 
        }


        $('#map').show();
    }
}
// // // // // // // //
```

Comment: Why are you using the `String` method?  Try excluding that method from your code..

Answer (score 0):

```
    // // // // // // // // Ajax returns from PHP
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var tLat = getCookie("tLat");
        var tLng = getCookie("tLng");

        var options = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(tLat, tLng),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Creating the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);



        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(obj[0][2]), parseFloat(obj[0][1]));

        //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map });

        var marker;

        for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(obj[i].lat), parseFloat(obj[i].lng));

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map });
        }

        $('#map').show();
    }
}
// // // // // // // //
```